# Material UI Slider -- create multiple cursors to reflect a range of values

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to put multiple pointers (thumbs) on the following material UI Slider component.

I've tried updating the values listed in state to be an array of values and testing the thumb property.

I would like the Slider to have icons on both ends of the bar, so that when the pointers are dragged it can reflect a range of values. The component is currently listed in the "lab" section of material ui.

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Slider from '@material-ui/lab/Slider';


const styles = {
  root: {
    width: 300,
  },
  slider: {
    padding: '22px 0px',
  },
};

class SimpleSlider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 50,
  };

  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({value});
    console.log(event)
  }


  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Typography id="label">{value}</Typography>
        <Slider
          classes={{ container: classes.slider }}
          value={value}
          aria-labelledby="label"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

SimpleSlider.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleSlider);
```

Comment: Unless Google decides to add the feature in their Slider component, I don't see any way of achieving this with the component as it is now. Have you considered using two sliders one above the other, where one handles min and the other handles max? Maybe also add controls in the handler so that max is never less than min, etc...

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, this feature is available now by passing an array to `defaultValue` prop:

```js
<Slider
  track="inverted"
  aria-labelledby="track-inverted-range-slider"
  getAriaValueText={valuetext}
  defaultValue={[20, 37]}
  marks />
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/o1nxv